# Spyder 5 missing dependencies - spyder_kernels version error

Tags: python, spyder

[image]

Spyder gives me error message like above, but I cannot solve it.

I think the version of spyder_kernels should be 2.0.1 at least, but I already updated my version as 2.0.1.

Why I get such warning message? & How can I solve it?

I reinstalled spyder-kernels both conda and pip, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) That error message is caused by a bug in Spyder and it was fixed in our 5.0.1 version, released on April 16th 2020.

You can safely ignore it for now because it incorrectly reports that the right version of `spyder-kernels` is missing, when it's actually installed.

Comment: I installed the standalone version of Spyder and am trying to point it at my system's python3 instead of the one Spyder uses by default, and got this error today. I am attempting to run `pip install spyder-kernels` because I want to use pip to install packages, since I am not using anaconda. Is this still a bug?