# Spyder 5.0.3 still shows missing dependencies

Tags: anaconda, dependencies, spyder

After reading the answer to a similar problem here:
[Spyder 5 missing dependencies - spyder_kernels version error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66952832/spyder-5-missing-dependencies-spyder-kernels-version-error)

the solution states, that the issue is resolved in Spyder 5.0.1. I'm using Spyder 5.0.3 with Anaconda and still get the missing dependencies message, although all requirements are met:

[Spyder 5.0.3 missing dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIECI.png)

I don't have problems with the functionality of Spyder, it's just the message which pops up at start. Any solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: I would love to get an answer to this as well. Mine says its missing 'paramiko'.