# Spyder complains about missing dependency paramiko

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I just upgraded Anaconda and Spyder to the latest version (Spyder 5.1.5), but since that I get an error message every time I start Spyder:

[image]

However, I have tried to install and update paramiko with both `conda install paramiko` and `conda update paramiko`, which appears to be of version 2.8.1 (this is the output from `conda list` about paramiko:

```
paramiko                  2.8.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
```

I'm not sure if I even use this package, but I would be much happier if I didn't get this error message upon Spyder startup.

Comment: It's actually a bug I guess. Pls, check below link..
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66959690/15358800

Comment: @Bhargav, but it says that that bug was fixed almost two years ago, and I just got the latest Spyder version?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Perhaps you're starting Spyder from a different environment than the one where you installed Paramiko. Please run the following code in the IPython console and also in the Anaconda Prompt to check: `import sys; sys.executable`.

Comment: In the ipython console it returns `'C:\\Anaconda3\\python.exe'`. In the Anaconda prompt it of course returns `'import' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` because the anaconda prompt is a Windows command line, not a python interpreter.

However, running `import paramiko` in the ipython console renders an ImportError from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl (DLL load failed). This sounds suspicious. Is a package broken? Which one?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
conda update paramiko
```

If it does not work:

```
pip uninstall paramiko
pip install pyqt5==5.12
pip install pyqtwebengine==5.12
pip install paramiko==2.4.0
```

Comment: This broke my installation. When launching Spyder from within an environment, I get
 File "C:\Users\<Username>\.conda\envs\phd\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\_vendor\packaging\version.py", line 264, in __init__
    match = self._regex.search(version)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: conda update paramiko worked great! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem is caused by the "DLL load failed while importing _openssl" (you can try `import paramiko` in ipython kernel to see the errors), so you can go to the website https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html to download  openssl for your computer according to the system. After installation, try `import paramiko` again, and you'll find no errors this time. Then restart spyder you'll get the problem fixed.

Comment: **ATTENTION** I tried the Win64 installer light and it ends with something like : Pay: 10$ once, may more once, pay 5$ regularly... OpenSSL may be open but is not free.